# Paracol background color not extending all the way to the edges of the page

Tags: color, geometry, paracol

I'm exploring the possibilities offered by `paracol` to typeset multi-column documents. This is what I have come up with so far:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[top=1cm, bottom=1cm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\backgroundcolor{c[0]}[rgb]{0, 0.7, 0}

\begin{document}
    \begin{paracol}{2}
        \begin{leftcolumn}
            \lipsum[2-4]
        \end{leftcolumn}
        \begin{rightcolumn}
            \lipsum[1-3]
        \end{rightcolumn}
    \end{paracol}
    
\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

As you can see the background color of the left column does not extend all the way to the left, top and bottom edge of the page.

How can I get the background color to extend to the left, top and bottom edge of the page? Can I do this with `paracol`?

Comment: \backgroundcolor is provided by paracol and only applies to one column at a time.  Columns do not extend to the top and bottom of the page.  There are other ways to apply background colors outside the margins.

Answer (score 3):

The `\backgroundcolor` command also accepts parameters to extend the background color, like:

```
\backgroundcolor{region(x0,y0)(x1,y1)}[mode]{color}
```

So, you would need something like:

```
\backgroundcolor{c[0](1cm,1cm)(0.25cm,1cm)}[rgb]{0, 0.7, 0}
```

Where `0.25cm` is half of the gap between columns and `1cm` is page margins.

Here is the explanation about these parameters from [the documentation](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/paracol/paracol.pdf):

> The optional `(x0,y0)` is to enlarge the region to be painted shifting its left-top and right-bottom corner outside by the dimension `x0` horizontally and `y0` vertically, or to shrink it with negative dimensions. This extension can be asymmetric giving another optional `(x1,y1)` so that it acts on the right-bottom corner while let `(x0,y0)` shift only the left-top corner. Moreover, you may make each extension infinite by giving `10000pt` (about `3.5m`) to `x0`, `y0`, `x1` and/or `y1` so that the corresponding region edge is shifted to the paper edge. Furthermore, this infinite extension can be terminated at the point `α` inside the corresponding paper edge by giving `10000pt − α` (`α ≤ 1000pt`) to an extension parameter `x0`, etc.